# Unable to setter property Foreground for a label

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, setter

I'm trying to build a style template using a resource dictionary. I am having issues setting a foreground property to a label.

I obviously am missing the logic here, could someone please explain to me what I am misunderstanding and how to correctly apply this

When I remove the

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
```

and run the project, everything is fine

However with that line in, I get the following error

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Label' threw an exception.' Line number '31' and line position '135'.
```

Here is the current code

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource STAC_FontFamily_Standard}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource STAC_FontSize_Medium}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />            
        <Setter Property="Template">            
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">                    
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"                              
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have so far tried the following combinations that I have logged and more besides

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="AliceBlue" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource STAC_Col_Label_Fg}"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground"  Value="AliceBlue"/>

        Also tried
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>

        with
        TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
        inside the content presenter
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>` does of course work in a Label Style. With what you've show here, we can't tell why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Class this as closed, steep learning curve these templates, if you add a resource of type brush when it needs to be a colour or vice versa , it seems to cause issues difficult to trace